# simple grading function in haskell wont work

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a simple function in haskell which takes a list of marks and then finds the average and returns a string based on this average. I keep getting multiple errors and cannot figure out why. Some of these errors are

```
haskel_tutorial.hs:12:17: error:
    * Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of `div'
      from the context: Num a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   gradeRating :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> String
        at haskel_tutorial.hs:4:1-37
      Possible fix:
        add (Integral a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            gradeRating :: forall a. Num a => [a] -> String
    * In the expression: sum marks `div` 10
      In an equation for `avg': avg = sum marks `div` 10
      In an equation for `gradeRating':
          gradeRating marks
            | avg >= 60 && avg <= 70 = "alright"
            | avg >= 90 && avg <= 100 = "perfect"
            | otherwise = "not good enough"
            where
                avg = sum marks `div` 10
   |
12 |     where avg = sum marks `div` 10
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```
import Data.List
import System.IO 

gradeRating :: Num a => [a] -> String

gradeRating marks

    | avg >= 60 && avg <= 70 = "alright"
    | avg >= 90 && avg <= 100 = "perfect"
    | otherwise = "not good enough"

    where avg = sum marks `div` 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let’s have a look at the signature of the `div` function: `div :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`. So, in order to use `div` in this function, you need to have an `Integral` constraint — which is exactly what the error message is telling you.